# How is this servlet returning the contents of a view?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm looking at this servlet that matches a route:

```
 @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<Function<HttpServletRequest, Matcher>, Handler<Matcher>> handlerEntry : handlerMap.entrySet()) {
      Matcher matcher = handlerEntry.getKey().apply(req);
      if (matcher != null) {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        handlerEntry.getValue().handle(req, resp, matcher);
        return;
      }
    }
    resp.setStatus(404);
  }
```

reference: https://github.com/spullara/twickery/blob/master/src/main/java/twickery/web/Router.java#L59

You can see the view templates here: https://github.com/spullara/twickery/tree/master/src/main/resources/templates

I'm confused as to how they are linked together, I presume somehow returning from the servlet, somewhere it takes the return and then uses that as the 'model' to inject into the view.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

The magic is done in the line `handlerEntry.getValue().handle(req, resp, matcher);`.

Sorry, I won't download that code, but check the code of `Handler.getValue().handle()`. I'm quite sure that is responsible for rendering the view. The hint is that the `handle()` method receives the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, so it can get any of the parameters from the request, and write anything to the response.

Comment: the files are in, you don't have to download: https://github.com/spullara/twickery/tree/master/src/main/java/twickery/web  I can't find what you are suggesting...